# Bind Shift to Joypad by using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, game-controller

I use the Xbox 360 Gamepad to control my complete mouse.

My question is: *Is there a way to bind Shift on the LB or the RB Button?*

They were marked as number 5 and number 6 by the JoyStick Test Script

Comment: Telling us what program you used to allow your gamepad to control your mouse might help... details are important when asking questions, so please provide as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To do a simple key mapping:

```
Joy5::Send {Space}
```

If you want the joystick button to act like the shift key while you hold it down, you should use one of the techniques described in [Remapping a Joystick to Keyboard or Mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm).

Also see [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) for a full list of key and joystick button names.

BTW: I assume you've seen the [Using Joystick as a Mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickMouse.htm) page, but if you haven't, it's quite useful.